# How can I fix these small dents caused by falling seed pods?

Tags: dent

My driveway is under a tree that drops seeds that are three to five inches long and two to three inches in diameter.
[image: seed pod]

I recently noticed that it has caused these small dents in the hood of my car.  (In the picture below the dent is just right and below of center)
The center of the dent looks like as if it was made by a nail set.

[image: car hood with dent]

Is there a way to fix these or do I just leave these alone. You only see it if you’re at a certain angle. But I’m afraid that I will keep collecting these dents.

Comment: Whatever you do, don’t do this - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4fBbhyzE9A

Comment: Avoid parking under that tree when its dropping seed pods or put up a canopy to shield your car if you cannot park anywhere away from that tree. YouTube videos for various methods of dent repairs.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I fix these small dents caused by falling seed pods?

It will be more trouble than it's worth. Feel free to get some quotes if you don't believe me.

Those dents are now a feature of your car. You should consider fixing those rust spots though since they make the car far more unsightly than the small dents.

> Is there a way to fix these or do I just leave these alone. You only see it if you’re at a certain angle. But I’m afraid that I will keep collecting these dents.

Stop parking your car under this tree or have someone cut down the tree.